# Return a string of all traders’ names sorted alphabetically with spaces in java8?

Tags: java-8

I was just playing with `Java 8 streams` and trying to return a string of all traders’ names sorted alphabetically.

```
public class PuttingIntoPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trader raoul = new Trader("Raoul", "Cambridge");
        Trader mario = new Trader("Mario","Milan");
        Trader alan = new Trader("Alan","Cambridge");
        Trader brian = new Trader("Brian","Cambridge");

        List<Transaction> transactions = Arrays.asList(
            new Transaction(brian, 2011, 300), 
            new Transaction(raoul, 2012, 1000),
            new Transaction(raoul, 2011, 400),
            new Transaction(mario, 2012, 710),  
            new Transaction(mario, 2012, 700),
            new Transaction(alan, 2012, 950)
        );

        // Query 4: Return a string of all traders’ names sorted alphabetically.
        String traderStr = transactions.stream()
                .map(t -> t.getTrader().getName())
                .sorted()
                .reduce("", (n1, n2) -> n1 + n2);
        System.out.println(traderStr);
    }
}
```

The output I get is like below:

```
AlanBrianMarioMarioRaoulRaoul
```

I want to show like below

```
 Alan Brian Mario Mario Raoul Raoul
```

How can I do that ?

I used lombok to generate setter getter all those boiler plates

```
@Setter @Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Trader {
    private String name;
    private String city;
}
```

Transaction

```
@Setter @Getter 
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Transaction {
    private Trader trader;
    private int year;
    private int value;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: @JB - I already went through the link and developed below code, but I dont understand how to satisfy the need of mine

Comment: You could change your code to `.reduce((n1, n2) -> n1 + " " + n2).orElse("");` or better, because usually more efficient: `.collect(Collectors.joining(" "));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is how you are reducing the `Stream`.

As currently written, this reduce `.reduce("", (n1, n2) -> n1 + n2);` will simply concatenate the 2 `String` without any whitespace. To achieve what you want, you have to add to change the `n1 + n2` to `n1 + " " + n2`. However, since you want to **collect** all the elements of the `Stream` into a single `String`, you should use[Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

Therefore, you should change your code to:

```
String traderStr = transactions.stream()
                .map(t -> t.getTrader().getName())
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```